# JQuery unable to read property when trying to use autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to follow [this article](http://www.jamiemaguire.net/index.php/2017/04/08/how-to-implement-an-autocomplete-control-with-asp-net-mvc-and-json/) but my program does not seem to define any list of items. I've set up my script (and ensured it works by inserting an `alert()`)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cname").autocomplete(
            {
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Contacts/Index",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { Prefix: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                },
            });
    })
```

And I already have a `ContactsController`. In it, I've added as the article suggests,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(string Prefix)
    {
        //Note : you can bind same list from database
        var contacts = _context.Contacts.ToList();

        var names = (from N in contacts
                     where N.Name.StartsWith(Prefix)
                     select new { N.Name });
        return Json(names, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When the page loads and I click/focus on the appropriate input text box, console throws an error,

[image: img]

I've looked at the source and it seems to break at this line in jquery,

```
_value: function()
{
    return this.valueMethod.apply(this.element, arguments);
}
```

(which is why I've concluded that my action is not being reached, because there's nothing to `apply`). Any thoughts on what could be going on here?

My `Contact` model looks like this:

```
[HandleError]
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Name ...")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Type")]
    public string ContactType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Phone:")]
    public long ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint in the controller action to verify it isn't being reached? I would also edit your select clause to be `select new { Name = N.Name });` to match what your javascript handler is expecting

Comment: Yup, I have. The breakpoint is never reached :(

Comment: It's gotta be a client side issue but I have no clue what it is. I spent a good hour thinking it's my URL in the ajax call, but now I'm not so sure, it seems fine to me